# Name must not be null in android gradle

Tags: android, gradle, null

I'm brand new to installing libraries in android studio and I've run into trouble. I keep on getting the error, name must not be null, when trying to set up my dependencies. I'm trying to install [this library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2366).

Here is the build.gradle code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.webbj.imageeditor"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations{
    compile
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.5'
    **compile group: "com.isseiaoki", module: "simplecropview", version: "1.1.5"**
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':libraries:SimpleCropView')
```

The error happens on the line surrounded by stars. 
I would really appreciate anyone to help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line instead of that line.

```
compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.5'
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the error:                                                                
    Error: Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to 
    configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project 
    :libraries:SimpleCropView.

Comment: Remove this line also: compile project(':libraries:SimpleCropView')

Answer (score 0):

For people that still run into this error:

under dependencies add:

```
implementation project("com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.1.5")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is "-" special character in internal module...I changed the module name and it's fixed!